# How to detect if cell value appears twice in one day

Tags: mysql, date, sum

Apologies in advance for the vagueness of the title. This is an issue that is stumping me and I struggled to get any more specific.

First of all, to help visualise my problem I've uploaded a photo of my database to https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVDZU.jpg.

Basically, I've been adding up payments in my database and have run into a complex (contextually to my understanding of MySQL, anyway, which is mediocre at best) problem.

I want to calculate the number of times any given customer (customer_id) has a job_id payment of both 17 & 12 in one day. If they do, I then want to calculate the added cost of them. However, I'd like to run this query throughout the whole database between 2 specific dates (eg. 2016-01-01 -- 2016-05-06) and generate the total income during this period.

In the picture I link to above, the customer with a customer_id of 1658 has two payments - one of them with a job_id of 12, one of them 17. Therefore, I would like to add the the cost of both these (6.00 + 19.80) together, as well as anyone else who falls under this criteria, and come to a total figure.

Just to clarify, the customer (with a customer_id of 1913) below the rows I refer to would also fall under this category.

I've tried my best at getting something together, but admittedly I'm completely lost.

Thanks in advance,
Liam

Comment: The way I work these kind of problems out is to break it down. first of all try and find out how you can get check for two entries of 17 and 12 from the same id. Don't worry about the dates at first. Once you got this working, then work out how  to get the dates. I could work this out with a little time, but I have a headache today.

Comment: Only output rows where a customer had both 17 and 12 on the same day, and sum the income of those 17 and 12 jobs for the date period?

Comment: @Bohemian Exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Is that a comma delimited value? Arrrrrgh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to itself, once for each job type:

```
select
  count(*) quantity,
  sum(a.cost + b.cost) total
from mytable a
join mytable b on b.customer_id = a.customer_id
  and a.date = b.date
where a.date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-05-06'
and a.job_id = 17
and b.job_id = 12
```

If you want a breakdown by `customer_id`, add `a.customer_id` to the selected columns and add `group by customer_id`.

Comment: I haven't ever come across joining a table to itself, so apologies for my ignorance here. Obviously if I enter the above query into SQL, I'll get an error message -- but why? I have changed 'mytable' to 'entry'. I can't really recognise anything else I'd want to change.

Also, I don't need to breakdown the results - I just need to know the total between any two given dates.

Comment: @liam make sure all column names are correct (cost, and date are something else in your schema), and if they are right, post the whole error message here as a comment

Comment: @liam I just noticed I have a typo: "in" should have been "on". It's changed in the answer now.

Comment: @bohemian, I think you need more coffee!

Comment: The query produces no results. 0 quantity and total is null, any idea why?

Comment: @liam yes, I know exactly why. The date range had a typo (a hazard of thumbing code on an iPhone) is was `between '2016-01-01' and '2015-05-06'`, which of course will return nothing. I've corrected it to `between '2016-01-01' and '2016-05-06'`.